# AWS: Autoscaling based on the size of the queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

AWS auto scaling works based on the load (number of concurrent requests). It works perfectly for web sites and web APIs. However there are situations in which the number of required EC2 instances is not related to the requests but it depends on something else such as number of items in a queue.

For example an order processing system which pulls the orders from a custom queue (and not SQS) might need to scale out to process the order quicker. How can we make this happpen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto scaling groups can be configured to scale in or out by linking their scaling policies to Cloud Watch alarms. Many people use CPU utilization as a scaling trigger but you can use any Cloud Watch metric you like. In your case you could use your queue's ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible metric.

For example, if you create an alarm that fires when the ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible > 500 and link that to the scale out policy of your auto scaling group, the group will create new instances whenever the queue has more that 500 messages in it.